# Error compilar app firebase build.gradle

Tags: compilar, build.gradle

Quiero añadir a mi app firebase, he seguido las instruciones de la web de firebase para poder compliarle en mi build.gradle, pero al compilar  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'  me da este error, y no se que tengo mal, me ayudan por favor? Gracias. Dejo mi build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:+'
compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-material-viewset:+'
compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-westeros-viewset:+'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'






}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

y el error que me da:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: 
Multiple dex files define 
Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents;
```

Comment: Arriba de `dependencies` agrega esta linea, compile y dinos que pasa: `dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}`

Comment: Pruebe con File-->Invalidar Chache y Reiniciar. Luego Buil - Invalidate Caches/Restart. Si no funciona verifique este link. http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14 Encontre un problema similar en SO en Ingles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el error Ismael:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define

El error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

o  el error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

:

Es solucionado habilitando el soporte Multidex dentro de tu `build.gradle` :

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Habilita soporte multidex.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

El error es causado porque la especificacion de un ejecutable Dalvik indica un limite del numero total de métodos que pueden ser referenciados en un archivo .DEX como 65,536, si tienes una cantidad mayor debes habilitar el soporte.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html